# Is the term 'field' too technical when giving messages on a form?

Tags: forms, terminology, language

When writing help or validation messages on a form I usually write something along the lines of:

- "This **field** is required"
- "5 **fields** need to be corrected on this form"
- etc

Is the term **field** too technical or is it a widely understood by the general public/users of tinternet?

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: It's always good to question stuff like this that otherwise would just be presumed as true. '*Well off course people understand it... I think*'

Comment: I have always wondered why people actually call it "field".

Comment: Maybe ask http://english.stackexchange.com/ @Bart?

Comment: [Saved you the effort](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147492/why-is-a-field-on-a-form-called-a-field) @BartGijssens

Comment: For me it's not so much that the term "field" is too technical, but that there are much better alternatives easily available "Please enter your name", "Your name is required", etc.

Comment: From the answers on the ELU site arises this alternative for required fields: "please fill in all the blanks."

Comment: @Bart Gijssens: it is terminology from the 80-column card punch; a "field" was the term for several consecutive columns containing a single data item, like for example 6 cols containing a pre-Y2K date. The set of all fields is a "recod".

Comment: With the context, a sentence like "this field has an error" is understandable - but Iain is right, there are better ways to communicate that.

Comment: Please make sure that all the white rectangles on this page have some black in them.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In short yes - unless you are dealing with a technical audience.

**Instead, refer to what is required in this case.** If it's name, say 'Your name is required'.

One useful bit of advice that all UX people should stick to is 'decode your language'. That means remove technical jargon and get rid of code names for projects and abbreviations. Many UX people coming from a technical background have a big problem with this as it goes against most of their programming instincts.

Comment: I agree with the intuition here, but it doesn't deal well with the second example "5 fields need to be corrected on this form". You sometimes end up with long lists (in red, often :( ) at the top of the page  of _all_ the things you're missing, which is also a bit discouraging. Synonyms like item, spot, area, piece of info, etc. could work better for that example but I haven't found one that fully convinces me.

Comment: Can you please provide some evidence for your point of view? Frankly, I'm not convinced that "field" is an intimidatingly technical term for the typical Internet user.

Comment: I don't have evidence that I can share but in order to convince yourself I would suggest testing the term with users. No matter how experienced I am the users will answer your particular question with more authority. I can only say that field is not something I would not expect to test well with users. Other terms like 'Radio Button' would have a similar response even though we know the term well.

Comment: Amp - in the case of you have multiple fields failing you still don't need to say fields. You can say 'Please check below for missing or incorrect information.' or 'The information marked in read is either missing or incorrect'.

Comment: I found this article that seems to support your view, which I put in my own answer: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/define-techy-words-old-users/

Comment: I won't downvote this answer, but I did upvote an alternative. At one level I can kind-of agree that avoiding "field" in some cases might be better, I think that most people have seen it used enough to understand it by now.

Comment: as mentioned on other comments on other answers there may be occasions where I need to refer to the fields as a group rather than individually. In these scenarios what alternative to 'fields' would you suggest is used?

Comment: Thanks you @Kevin for the link to the article. TecBrat - to test your hypothesis I'd suggest asking your target audience. When does the average user use field? Terms like 'Radio button' also fit into this category. Lastly for multiple either list them or use something like 'The information marked in red is incorrect' or something less clunky! People know what information means, along with 'what you have entered' and other non tech terms.

Comment: is 'input' too techy? e.g. 'All input required'

Comment: I'd say 'input' would be understood but not be friendly. It's not quite as bad as saying 'affirmative' instead of yes but it does have a techy feel. Language is an emotive thing and getting the right terminology is more than just if the user understands it. Speaking to the user as if they are a human is probably the most important thing. When you are asked to type in a security code most use 'enter' rather than 'input' for that reason. Or 'type in'.

Answer (score 24):

A "field" wouldn't just apply to the internet (or technical manifestations of forms).

Any form where the user fills in spaces contains "fields" and it's common on paper forms (such as application forms, tax return forms, etc.) to see text such as *Please complete all the fields marked with a * *, etc.

So I'd say this is a widely used term in the "real world". So the use of the term "fields" in this scenario would be generally accepted and makes perfect sense.

Comment: I think you'll find the average user doesn't know what 'feilds' mean even if your peers do. Be careful of assumed knowledge in UX.

Comment: Could you post some evidence (like a reference to a UX study) to support your view?

Comment: Sorry nothing I can share.

Comment: Interestingly, no definition of "field" in the Oxford English Dictionary matches what you describe here, so my suspicion is that this is a back-formation from the computer-related meaning (which in the OED's definition is specifically restricted to use as computer terminology).  This is therefore probably a new meaning, and perhaps not widely understood. The only relevant def. is "III.15.f *Computers*. A set of one or more characters in a record, or a group of columns on a punched card, which together represent a single item of information; an item of information that can be so represented."

Comment: (That's from the 2009 version of the OED CDROM, which includes changes that had been prepared up until that year)

Comment: Hi @Jules, yes, see my question on [english.stackexchange.com](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147492/why-is-a-field-on-a-form-called-a-field). According to sources on that, "field" dates from 1929. My point wasn't that it pre-dates computers, more that it is widely used outside of computing.

Answer (score 6):

The term "field" is not sufficient on it's own without context - we should strive to reduce surprise for our users by filling in the context for a term that could arguably be considered 'technical.'

"**Field** errors, Last Name, SSN, Home Phone are required." doesn't do any good to explain what the user should do - and really what the heck a 'field' error is.

"The form is incomplete, please fill out the following **fields** before submitting the form: Last Name, SSN, and Home Phone." (emphasis added) - This is a message that puts enough context to the term 'field' that it is easily understood, even if the term itself is unknown to the user.

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question on the use of 'field'

Comment: @DaveHaigh Question: "Is the term 'field' too technical when giving messages on a form?" Answer: "The term 'field' is not sufficient on it's own without context..." Can you indicate how that fails to answer the question?

Comment: fair point I take that back. re reading your answer I take from it that you think the term 'field' is acceptable if used in conjunction with further explanatory texts, I misread it previously

Answer (score 3):

According to [this report from the Nielsen Norman Group](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/define-techy-words-old-users/),

> Our report on designing websites for senior citizens includes the following usability guideline:
>
> **"If using web or browser-related terms, consider defining them in place. Avoid using them if they are not necessary."** [emphasis theirs, not mine]
>
> [...]
>
> Many users today understand standard web-related terms. But, in this study, many seniors were unsure about web terminology, such as page, homepage, website, or the web.
>
> [...]
>
> Some of the points and questions seniors made about web-related terms:
>
> - “Is this a website or a web page? I don’t know the difference.”
> - “I don’t know what ‘URL’ means. What is that?”
> - “I don’t always know exactly what the word ‘web’ means.”
> - “Is the homepage part of a website?”
> - Another user couldn’t find an item on a particular page and said, “I don’t think I see it under this site.”

If these users were being confused by terms like "web page" and "URL," it's likely they'd be confused by a word like "field." So, if you're expecting a significant number of your users to be seniors or inexperienced with computers, this report suggests that it would be best to avoid that word.

Comment: thanks for that, interesting read. I agree when dealing with a large number of non-techy users even the simplest of technical terms can be misunderstood. any suggestion for alternatives to the word field? I know about inline messages and referring to specific fields e.g. "Enter a valid email address" but there may be occasions when I need an alternative to 'field'

Answer (score 1):

The thing is I can think of no scenario where saying "field" would feel *better* than actually specifying what informations you are referring to.

(EDIT: as discussed in the comments, whether such an alternative actually exists in every scenario is another question)

So is it okay to be lazy instead of being precise about the thing you are talking about?

Well, **no**.

Comment: How would you word the following? "5 fields need to be corrected on this form"

Comment: Please fill the following informations:, following with — guess what — the 5 missing informations.

Comment: `fill` or `correct`. In fact the things needed to be changed are so vague that you can't afford not to be precise. What will a user think if you say "1 field needs to be corrected" and he has no idea which one is it? Or what the actual correction is (why it's failing)?

Comment: what if you need to summarise how many fields need to be corrected? specifically the number of fields. how would you word that?

Comment: Well to be honest it would be okay to just say "field" if you give the explicit list afterwards, not that I'm not sure it is *really* necessary to give such a number. "informations" also seems like a good alternative as it describes what the fields *contain* not what they *are* (who care they are fields, eventually? If you could have a recognition system for audio, you'd ask the users to say their answers out loud and it'd work too).

Comment: well you said you could 'think of no scenario', but that was just one scenario where you may not be referring to an individual field and so the term 'fields' is required (or an alternative less techinical term)

Comment: Touché. Except I said "no scenario where […] better than specifying", so, as to speak, using a more precise word than "field" is *better*. In the case of a general summary, there might not be any more precise alternatives, but it doesn't change the fact that such an alternative **would** be better if it existed (or if you can think of one in your situation). We can continue this by chat if you feel like it.

Comment: Just commenting to note that "missing informations" isn't proper English. You'd probably say "missing pieces of information", "missing responses" or "missing entries".

Comment: @JamieBull "information" is one of those weird collective-plural words, so "missing information" is also valid for referring generically to multiple fields.  Only when adding a specific number do you need to switch to one of those.

Comment: these are the first mentions of possibly suitable alternatives to 'fields' - 'responses' and 'entries'. 'Information/s' isn't suitable as there may not be missing information, there may just be validation errors. Referring to the fields themselves, 'information' isn't a suitable alternative.

Comment: @DaveHaigh: what about 'items'?

Comment: @MarjanVenema I think 'item' is the best alternative to 'field' so far. 'Response' and 'entry' could imply that the user has already entered some information in that field but they may not have.

Comment: Well `item` is very close to `thing`. I'm not sure saying "5 missing things" is very relevant. Maybe you could just say "Encountered 5 errors", since you're emphasizing the number of corrections to make (possibly several on the same item), and not the fields themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As @Liam pointed out, the term "field" is used in other contexts and may be known to most users out there. Nevertheless, your application doesn't really requires the "field", but the information it should contain.

So, stating "your e-mail is required to complete your registration" is more accurate than "the field 'e-mail' is required to perform this action".